# How to make Eclipse warn me when file is updated externally

Tags: eclipse

I am doing Android development with Eclipse Juno.

When developing, if a file is updated using and external editor, the file in my Eclipse environment can be updated either automatically or manually, which can be adjusted with a setting in "Window >> preferences >> General >> Workspace"

My question is: How can I make Eclipse automatically update the file after external edits but also prompt me about it. (Like visual-studio does)